# I have to calculate values from two files and store the result in another file -- using shell

Tags: shell-script

I have to calculate values from two files and store the result in output file. In the output file, each record shows the product of records with the same name in input files.

file one

```
s1 10
s2 20 
s3 25 
s4 25  
s5 25   
s6 20 
s7 25 
s8 25
```

file two

```
s2 4
s1 10
s3 2 
s4 3 
s6 3
s7 2
s8 2
```

output

```
s1 100 
s2 80 
s3 50
s4 75 
s6 60 
s7 50 
s8 50
```

---

Note: I have to use a shell.

Comment: Go for a language like Ruby.

Comment: Is it homework?, if so then add homework tag, and tell us if there are any language constraints.

Comment: Can you edit your own question: don't add amendments in comments, and have me edit the question.

Comment: Why do you _have_ to use the shell? Which shell do you have to use? Many shells (bash for example) can't deal with non integers. Is that an issue here?

Comment: sorry Richard i'm new to here

Comment: So each line can have a different number of fields and fields are separated by commas. Is that correct? You still have not told us _which shell you need to use_. The answers will be very different for different shells. Does your shell support arrays for example?

Comment: Do you have to use *only* shell commands, or are commands like **awk** allowed. It would help if you post all the constraints in your question.

Comment: @richard This site doesn't have a homework tag (like most other Stack Exchange sites).

Comment: @gilles, you are correct this site does not have a homework tag. I would recommend the question just adds a note then.

Answer (score 1):

This script does what you need. It assumes that your files are always in the format of

```
id value, id2 value2, id3 value3
```

That is, it assumes comma separated fields and a consistent format across both files. It also assumes a recent version of `bash` that supports indexed arrays.
It also gives the correct output, that is the output you ask for and not the output you show (2x25 != 75 for example).

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Read each line of the first file into the 
## array lines1.
mapfile -t lines1 < file1
## Do the same for the 2nd file and the array lines2.
mapfile -t lines2 < file2


declare -A fields2
declare -A fields1
## Iterate through each element of $lines2
## and separate ids from values
for ((i=0; i<${#lines2[@]}; i++)); do
    while read id val
    do
        fields2["$id"]="$val"
    done < <(printf "%s\n" "${lines2[$i]//, /$'\n'}")
done

## Iterate through each element of $lines1, separate
## ids from values.
for ((i=0; i<${#lines1[@]}; i++)); do
    while read id val
    do
        ## Some ids don't exist in both files, set their 
        ## value to 1 to avoid errors.
        if [[ -z "${fields2[$id]}" ]]; then
            fields2[$id]=1
        fi
        ## Print the id and the result of the multiplication.
        printf "%s %d " $id  "$(( ${fields2[$id]} * $val ))";
    done < <(printf "%s\n" "${lines1[$i]//, /$'\n'}")
    echo "";
done
```